# dlmSmooth increases fluctuations

Tags: r, time-series, kalman-filter, state-space-models, dlm

I am currently working with State Space models for the first time and am trying to estimate an error correction model with an unobserved I(2) process, $\mu_t$. I have specified a model in R using the package dlm. My model has the form:

$$ \Delta s_t = \alpha_1 s_{t-1} + \alpha_2 p_{t-1} + \mu_{t} + \kappa_0 \Delta p_{t} + \kappa_1 \Delta p_{t-1} + \omega_1 \Delta s_{t-1} + \epsilon_t $$

$$ \mu_{t} = \mu_{t-1} + \Delta \mu_{t}$$

$$ \Delta \mu_t = \Delta \mu_{t-1} + \eta_t$$

where $\Delta s_t, s_{t-1}, p_{t-1}, \Delta p_t, \Delta p_{t-1}, \Delta s_{t-1}$  are data-observations, $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \kappa_0, \kappa_1, \omega_1$ are constant unknown parameters and $\mu_t$ is an unobserved I(2) process.

I am mainly interested in estimating the unknown parameter values $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ and the unobservered process $\mu_t$.

Implementing the model in R, I first specify the model by the following code and obtain the filtered parameter values. Hereafter I obtain the smoothed values.

```
dlmmodel2 <- function(alfa) {dlm(
  FF=matrix(c(1,1,-1,1,1,1,0),nr = 1), 
  GG=matrix(c(1,0,0,0,0,0,0,  0,1,0,0,0,0,0,  0,0,1,0,0,0,0,  0,0,0,1,0,0,0,  0,0,0,0,1,0,0,  0,0,0,0,0,1,0,  0,0,1,0,0,0,1), nr = 7),
  V = alfa[1],
  W =matrix(c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,   0,0,0,0,0,0,0,  0,0,0,0,0,0,0,  0,0,0,0,0,0,0,   0,0,0,0,0,0,0,  0,0,0,0,0,0,0,  0,0,0,0,0,0,alfa[2]), nr = 7),
  m0 = matrix(c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1),nr = 7), 
  C0 = matrix(c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,   0,0,0,0,0,0,0,  0,0,5,0,0,0,1,  0,0,0,0,0,0,0,   0,0,0,0,0,0,0,  0,0,0,0,0,0,0,  0,0,1,0,0,0,5), nr = 7), 
  X=F_matrix, # F_Matrix contains the data observations (col 3 and 7 are empty)
  JFF=matrix(c(1,2,0,4,5,6,0), nr=1) 
) 
}

#initial values
init1 <- c(2.1,1)

#model
model <- dlmMLE(y_vector,init1,dlmmodel2) #yvector contains Delta_s_t
model
parameter_results2 <- dlmmodel2(model$par)

#filter and smooth
filtered<- dlmFilter(y_vector, parameter_results2)
smoothed <- dlmSmooth(filtered)
```

My problem arise as I try to obtain the smoothed values. The obtained values range from 3 e+209 to -1 e+191 though my filtered values are in a much lower range.

**My question is: why is my smoothed values so (numerically) large? (see output below)**

```
> plot(filtered$m)
> filtered$m
Time Series:
Start = 1999 
End = 2017 
Frequency = 1 
          [,1] [,2]        [,3] [,4]      [,5]     [,6]        [,7]
1999 1.0000000    1  1.00000000    1 1.0000000 1.000000  1.00000000
2000 1.0283483    1  1.22242633    1 0.9961995 1.012915  0.54457382
2001 0.9213248    1  0.21543516    1 0.8005188 1.007066 -0.35293323
2002 0.9299682    1  0.53160130    1 0.8180312 1.007189  0.02261221
2003 0.9328907    1  1.01496822    1 0.8239033 1.007241  0.26599504
2004 0.9324971    1  1.15266894    1 0.8231204 1.007232  0.19794457
2005 0.9319144    1  0.94703263    1 0.8219661 1.007218 -0.01607025
2006 0.9314988    1  0.30847832    1 0.8211416 1.007209 -0.34454848
2007 0.9315001    1 -0.03187562    1 0.8211442 1.007209 -0.34235386
2008 0.9313951    1 -0.14680378    1 0.8210130 1.007191 -0.26428162
2009 0.9310889    1 -0.72624693    1 0.8205843 1.007147 -0.48839884
2010 0.9319146    1  0.43896849    1 0.8217332 1.007266  0.37800888
2011 0.9317131    1  0.17669692    1 0.8214527 1.007237  0.02991360
2012 0.9316768    1 -0.19409593    1 0.8214027 1.007232 -0.18156016
2013 0.9316803    1 -0.60983462    1 0.8214079 1.007232 -0.30928727
2014 0.9316748    1 -0.54629135    1 0.8214003 1.007231 -0.10740577
2015 0.9316805    1 -0.25928590    1 0.8214087 1.007232  0.10678342
2016 0.9316611    1  0.52341814    1 0.8213816 1.007229  0.48246605
2017 0.9316605    1  0.84370534    1 0.8213807 1.007229  0.39923137
>

> smoothed$s
Time Series:
Start = 1999 
End = 2017 
Frequency = 1 
               [,1]           [,2]           [,3]           [,4]           [,5]           [,6]
1999   1.000000e+00   1.000000e+00 -9.466652e+231   1.000000e+00   1.000000e+00   1.000000e+00
2000  3.439619e+209  6.190332e+197  1.701729e+213  3.255033e+196  1.000790e+212 -2.029970e+211
2001 -1.013215e+191 -1.003954e+177 -7.431703e+191 -5.630027e+175 -2.226889e+191 -7.003334e+189
2002 -9.117334e+175 -6.378055e+161  1.064459e+176 -5.483632e+160 -1.467380e+176 -7.720378e+174
2003  3.317407e+159 -1.130269e+146  4.784756e+161 -1.657647e+144  6.221140e+159  9.835280e+157
2004  6.630620e+145 -2.177203e+132  9.128879e+147 -2.182155e+130  6.581938e+145  7.359108e+143
2005  7.807999e+133  1.845376e+120  4.883447e+135  5.325280e+117  9.771700e+133  1.344280e+133
2006  3.443877e+120 -1.712517e+108 -2.018727e+123 -2.481098e+105  2.988215e+120  1.008803e+120
2007 -1.940769e+108  -3.597062e+95 -7.471470e+111  -6.241203e+94 -3.494084e+108 -2.497683e+107
2008  -4.174798e+95  -2.506133e+83  -3.241887e+98   6.105502e+82  -2.704219e+96  -2.974656e+95
2009   5.170978e+84  -1.197459e+72   1.458495e+87  -5.988552e+70   6.800202e+84   9.838138e+83
2010  -1.007168e+72  -2.888476e+60   2.190879e+75   1.197968e+59  -2.637143e+72  -1.420613e+71
2011   5.463719e+60  -7.203329e+48  -6.079742e+63   5.655312e+47   3.452379e+60   2.101814e+60
2012   3.870811e+48   9.011218e+36  -7.816310e+51   3.313523e+33   6.043987e+48  -3.248771e+48
2013   1.559516e+38   7.271353e+27  -1.127496e+43  -1.021232e+26   6.176949e+38  -6.562388e+37
2014  -2.202694e+27   1.420512e+16  -2.248650e+31  -2.071048e+14   2.786972e+27  -6.745094e+26
2015   2.775447e+16   1.235690e+04   5.069440e+19  -6.768663e+02   4.426600e+16   3.470204e+15
2016  -4.283332e+04   1.000000e+00   1.373019e+05   1.000000e+00  -1.779131e+04  -4.499139e+03
2017   9.316605e-01   1.000000e+00   8.437053e-01   1.000000e+00   8.213807e-01   1.007229e+00
               [,7]
1999 -6.761894e+231
2000  1.136702e+213
2001 -1.183163e+191
2002  2.204284e+175
2003  2.729704e+161
2004  3.381939e+147
2005  1.976811e+135
2006 -9.824642e+122
2007 -5.034451e+111
2008  -8.683889e+98
2009   1.006174e+87
2010   1.349258e+75
2011   1.247445e+64
2012   2.416943e+52
2013  -4.594289e+42
2014  -8.923618e+30
2015   2.568447e+19
2016  -4.045394e+04
2017   3.992314e-01
>
```

If I run the same code on a larger sample (1968-2017 instead of 2000-2017), I can estimate the filtered values but get the following error code when trying to obtain the smoothed values.

```
> smoothed <- dlmSmooth(filtered)
Error in dlmSmooth.dlmFiltered(filtered) : 
  error code 6 from Lapack routine dgesdd
```

**Does anyone know whether this can be fixed in any other way than reducing the time span?**

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot quite relate your code to your problem statement. When I print your GG matrix I get:

```
> matrix(c(1,0,0,0,0,0,0,  0,1,0,0,0,0,0,  0,0,1,0,0,0,0,  0,0,0,1,0,0,0,  0,0,0,0,1,0,0,  0,0,0,0,0,1,0,  0,0,1,0,0,0,1), nr = 7)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
[1,]    1    0    0    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    1    0    0    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    1    0    0    0    1
[4,]    0    0    0    1    0    0    0
[5,]    0    0    0    0    1    0    0
[6,]    0    0    0    0    0    1    0
[7,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    1
```

It looks like $\mu_t$  is in the third position of the state vector and $\Delta\mu_t$ in the seventh, but why there is a $-1$ in the third position in `FF` rather than a 1? It wouldn't matter (a change of sign in the latent process), but make me fear that I am misunderstanding something.

You set only two variances in `V` and `W`, but make no provision to ensure that they are non-negativa an remain so along the maximum likelihood estimation: try to replace by something like `exp(alpha[1])`  or `alpha[2]^2` (and modify the initial values accordingly).

Don't you say that you have five unknown parameters (other than the variances of the noises that I gather are `alpha[1]` and `alpha[2]`)?
If you want to estimate these parameters --which you need to in order to run your filter-- you should replace them in the proper places inside function `dlmmodel2`. If you intend these five parameters to be the five  elements of the state vector not already taken by $\mu_t$ and $\Delta\mu_t$, you should initialize them properly: it seems that you are giving them initial value 1 (in `m0`) and variance 0 (in `C0`). Is that what you intend?  How were the non-zero elements in `C0` chosen?

I seem to recall that I have had some trouble passing time series to some function in `dlm`. Try to pass plain matrices.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for your response.

Yes you are right that the third position in FF should be a 1 in order to match the model I have presented. This is a mistake on my behalf as I have simplified the model slightly in order to present it here.

So far, my estimates of the two variances have been positive, hence, I have not felt the need to restrict the parameters but on your recommendation I have now done so.

With regards to my five unknown parameters, you are right that I would like to obtain estimates of these. I have been unsure of how to include them properly in dlmmodel2 and hence I have chosen to include them as element 1,2,4,5,6 in my state vector. In this example I initialize them to 1, but I am continuously trying different initial values.

I see now that I have misinterpreted c0, and as my parameters are unknown c0 should in fact have a strictly positive diagonal. Changing this in my R code seems to do the trick and the two errors I previously got are now gone.

Thank you very much for your answer.